# MVC4 having trouble formatting text from database

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having trouble with showing my formatted SQL text.I have a form and Textarea where I put down comments. I wrote the following comment below that you see on the picture. I had a simple numbered list with no HTML I simply went from 1-5 pressed enter and it saved in the database just how I wrote it.

[image]

once I show that text on my page it looks like this

[image]

As you can see the text is mangled and it is not showing how I saved it in the database. How can I correct this? I have tried

```
@Model.comment and @Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.comment))
```

but it's not working any help would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [HtmlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/73z22y6h(v=vs.110).aspx). This will make the correct encoding.